# Installed platforms's not in the SDK folder and doesn't appear as target platforms

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I'm just getting started with Android development on my Win 7 machine. I have installed all the platforms from the SDK manager.
[image: SDK manager]

But when I go to preferences from Eclipse to add them, it shows only two of them.

[image: Eclipse preferences]

In the SDK folder even, there are only those two platforms.

[image: SDK folder]

I have deleted and re-installed some of the platforms (like 2.2) to see if they'd appear again but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me if I'm overlooking a step or something here? How can I add the other platforms too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SDK Location in Eclipse to `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`. That is where the SDK is located, as you can see in the `SDK Path` in SDK Manager.